# How to define different sequential value for different hosts in the same group in Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to define different sequential value for different hosts in the same group?

I have a job with multiple tasks that loops for every hosts in the host group.

For example: my_host group contains 3 hosts A, B, C and 5 tasks

The 5 tasks will run 3 times for each hosts A, B, C

However in 1 variable of the 5 tasks that I have, I want to pass a sequential value for each hosts

So variable 'sequential_var' will have value 1 in host A, value 2 in host B, and value 3 in host C

I have tried

```
- hosts: my_host
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - name: task1
      set_fact:
        sequential_var: {{ item }}
      with_sequence: start=1 end=3
```

the value ended up being 3 for all of the host when i actually want 1 for A, 2 for B and 3 for C

is there anyway for me to achieve what i actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**The variable 'sequential_var' will have value 1 in host A, value 2 in host B, and value 3 in host C**"*

A: Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[my_host]
A
B
C
```

Get the index of the host in the group, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: my_host
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    sequential_var: "{{ groups.my_host.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: sequential_var
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [A] => 
  sequential_var: '1'
ok: [B] => 
  sequential_var: '2'
ok: [C] => 
  sequential_var: '3'
```

The directive *serial* has no effect on the variable *sequential_var*. The value of *sequential_var* will be the index of the host in the group as ordered in the inventory.

Comment: i didn't think about that, thankyou so much for your answer :) !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign variable to hosts.

From ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups)

> You can store variable values that relate to a specific host or group in inventory. To start with, you may add variables directly to the hosts and groups in your main inventory file. As you add more and more managed nodes to your Ansible inventory, however, you will likely want to store variables in separate host and group variable files

You can do this while you configure your ansible hosts.

```
myhosts:
  hosts:
    A:
      id: 1
    B:
      id: 2
```

Comment: actually, i just want to pass the sequential value and i use loop because the hosts numbers may differ for every group. so i can't assign it just like that..